# ASP.NET MVC ApplicationDbContext Create

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-identity

Can someone explain what is create method used for?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
  {
  }

  public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
  {
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is used to create your own `DB Context` to use. Please refer to answers to this SO question --> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010113/replacing-automatically-created-applicationdbcontext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the References of this `Create` static method  you will find that this method has been used in `ConfigureAuth` method of the `Startup` partial class in `Startup.Auth.cs` file under `App_start` folder as follows:

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Removed other codes for brevity
    }
}
```

Here [CreatePerOwinContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn612979(v=vs.108)) registers a static callback which your application will use to get back a new instance of a specified type.
This callback will be called once per request and will store the object/objects in OwinContext so that you will be able to use them throughout the application.

[Here is more details with example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626120/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-extension-method-createperowincontext-in-owin-impleme)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it creates an new dbcontext instance will be stored in the OwinContext.